# Windows Mobile (MFC). How to make visible the most right part of CStatic (text label) with a long caption?

Tags: windows-mobile

For exmaple, this text:
"It is a very long text..."

For default CStatic it will looks like approximately so:
"It is a "

But I need something like this:
" text..."

Is it possible to make this without calculating the text length and deleting of an invisible part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911421.aspx) with DT_END_ELLIPSIS to achieve your goal.

Comment: My understanding (and I could be reading it wrong) is that he doesn't want to do the end elipsis, he actually wants to just show the "end" of the string that fits, rather than the default "start" of the text.

Comment: have the similar problem when drawing a multiline CStatic. I still don't know how to correctly use the scrollbar. I can only show it and handle its events, but I don't know how to update the CStatic. If I use the Invalidate() function then the application shows text in CStatic from the beginnig.

Comment: You can use ScrollWindowEx to help with the scrolling.  It will be a pain though.  Have you tried to make your own control inheriting from CStatic?  You should be able to override the OnPaint method to use DrawText() with DT_END_ELLIPSIS.

Answer (score 0):

The standard CStatic, which just wraps a basic Static control, doesn't have the capability to do this.  You'll have to create your own control that measures the text length and draws only the part you want (it might be doable with clipping regions as well, but it's still going to require manual drawing).